# YouTube's PubSubHubbub: identify whether video is newly added or only updated

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

The guide on [this](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/push_notifications) link tells it is possible to identify whether a video is new or updated via the `<yt:videoId>` element's value. My question is pretty straightforward: how? What changes with the `<yt:videoId>` element's value so I can distinguish between a new and an updated video?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please be more specific: describe in few words what is that you understood about  PubSubHubbub; then describe  your issue using a few more words (than only one).

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, your reading (quote):

> [...] tells it is possible to identify whether a video is new or updated via the `<yt:videoId>` element's value.

is incorrect.

The [specification](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/push_notifications) you referred to says:

> Note that you can use the `<yt:videoId>` element's value to identify the newly added or updated video.

That means that the value of `<yt:videoId>` is the ID of the video that is either a newly created video or an updated one.

Nothing changes with `<yt:videoId>`, since any video ID is an identifier that's unique during the entire lifetime of YouTube back-end (and website, and video for that matter).

But notice the presence of the XML elements `<published>` and `<updated>` within the YouTube's server notification: these two should make the difference between a new video and an updated one. Regrettably is that the official document mentioned does not specify at all what is to be expected from these two XML elements. (This very issue could well deserve to be reported to Google itself through its [own issue tracker site](http://issuetracker.google.com/).)

Furthermore, the experience of other developers dealing with this issue is inconclusive and contradictory (see for example [this article on Codeproject](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1229912/Push-Notification-PubSubHubBub-from-Youtube-to-Csh) and [this thread on Github](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/issues/177#issuecomment-695173100)): this means that over time the YouTube's back-end server implementation changed.

I recommend to experiment yourself with `<published>` and `<updated>`, such that to come up with your own educated guess to be used within your deployed application.

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed answer! I understood the problem and, indeed, created an issue in their tracker to ask them to enhance their docs

Comment: [Here is the link](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/184930316) to that issue report for those interested to follow up on it.